# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

Im' getting the error:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

This is the code:

```
foreach (array_unique($meeting) as $entry) {
    if (array_shift(array_values($meeting)) == $entry and $venue ==""  or $venue == $entry) {
        echo '<b><a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/racecard.php?venue='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>   </b> ';

        if ($venue =="") {
            $venue = array_shift(array_values($meeting));
        }

    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/racecard.php?venue='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>    ';
    }

}
```

I have seen other messages on here regarding it, but i cannot seem to solve the error

Comment: That's not full error message. There was also information about line number.

Comment: sorry errors seem to be on lines with array_shift(array_values($meeting));

Comment: I might be mistaken but all those conditions + the initial array_unique seem to boil down to: wrap the output for the first item in `<b>...</b>` ....unless $venue has been set earlier (before the loop) to something else than "".

Answer (score 2):

This error is because of the `array_shift()` function. You can't pass

```
array_values($meeting)
```

directly to this function you have to save it in a tmp variable for example:

```
$tmp = array_values($meeting);
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$venue = array_shift($tmp);  //Same for the if statement
```

For more information about `array_shift()` see the manual: https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

And a quote from there:

> mixed array_shift ( array **&**$array )

As you can see from the manual you have to pass it by reference (Because you can't change the signature of the function) and you can pass these by reference:

- Variables, i.e. foo($a)
- New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
- References returned from functions, i.e.:

[Passing by Reference](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

Like you can see in manual ([here](http://php.net/array_shift)) `array_shift` takes reference to the array not actual value.

So you have to assing `array_values($meeting)` to some variable and the use it with `array_shift`.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
 $meeting = array_unique($meeting);
 foreach ( $meeting as $entry) {
    $meeting = array_values($meeting);
    $meeting = array_shift($meeting);
    if ( $meeting == $entry && $venue ==""  || $venue == $entry)
    {
    echo '<b><a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/racecard.php?venue='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>   </b> ';
    if ($venue =="")
    {
    $meeting = array_values($meeting); 
    $venue = array_shift($meeting);
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<a href="http://mr-tipster.com/pages/racecard.php?venue='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a>    ';
    }
    }
```

Comment: still shows the errors